# Is there a way to activate a profile based on a file which is created during build?

Tags: maven, profile

I would like to activate my profile only when a file exists. This specific file is generated by a plugin in build. When I run maven install I have to do it a couple of times to achieve the desired result. But I want the whole process to happen in single build. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Profiles are activated at the very beginning of the build.

You cannot influence profile activation during the build itself.

Comment: Thank you but is there any other way through which I can achieve that maybe not using profiles?

Comment: For that, it would be better if you ask a new question in which explain which problem you want to solve (so what files you generate and for what purpose and how and why they need to trigger other plugins).